# Codeigniter 3.1.4 post request not receive form-data parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

`$_POST` return empty value.

`GET` request parameter are print.

but not print `POST` parameter which are returned as empty.

It's working before 6 months.

Comment: make sure your form is `<form method="POST" >`

Comment: what is the former mysql version (the one you used 6 month ago) and what's the current one?

Comment: Done.change to http to https in a config file.base_url variable.

Answer (score 1):

- Use (Profiler in CI) :

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

- check your php.ini file and comment out the following line `enable_post_data_reading = Off`
  or set it to `On`

```
;enable_post_data_reading = Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to **http to** **https in a config** file.base_url variable.

Example

$config['base_url'] = 'https:// example.com/';